# Populate a input[type=file] with drag and drop without ajax

Tags: file-upload, drag-and-drop

I have a form to create a profile and that profile takes a picture. I can't really ajax upload the picture because I would need the profile to be created to attach the image to it.

So is there a way to drag-drop a picture to just populate the file input the same way we do it  when we browse a file? I don't want it to be uploaded, just stored in the input.

PS: I know I can do server-side workaround but it is not the point of my question. Though if you think of any elegant solution, I'd love to hear it.

Thanks.